# How to create Scrollspy effect in AMP site?

Tags: javascript, web, amp-html, scrollspy

I am converting my old site to AMP. I am new to AMP. My old site contains a **Scrollspy** which I want to implement in the AMP site. There are a lot of functionality like `OffsetTop`, `clientWidth` are disabled in AMP. So is there any component in AMP that can help me implement it.

**Old Scrollspy Code**

In old code,I am storing the offsetTop of elements in an array and on clicking the horizontal tabs it will scroll to offsetTop value associated with it.And clicked tab becomes active by adding class active-tab

var section = document.querySelectorAll(".wordlistContainer");

```
let sections = {};
function setSections(){
  sections = {};    
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(section, function(e) {
      sections[e.id] = e.offsetTop;
  });
}
window.onscroll = function() {
  var scrollPosition = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;

  for (i in sections) {
    let sort_val = document.getElementById('sort-select').value;
    if(i.split('_')[0]==sort_val && sections[i] && sections[i] <= scrollPosition) {
      document.querySelector('.active-tab').classList.remove('active-tab');
      var active_now = document.querySelector('#Tab_'+ i.split('_')[1] )
      active_now.classList.add('active-tab');
      active_now.scrollIntoView();
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Try amp-position-observer + amp-animation components. Give us an example of your code, how you tried to implement it.

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov , I have added my code, I want to replace it with AMP code.I tried it with amp-position-observer + amp-animation but it doesn't allow toggling visibility or class.Thanks